# Why aren't bitwise operators as smart as logical "and\or" operators

Tags: c#, optimization, operators, bit-manipulation

I just noticed that bitwise operations aren't as "smart" as logical "and\or" operations and I wonder why?

Here's an example:

```
// For the record
private bool getTrue(){return true;}
private bool getFalse(){return false;}

// Since a is true it wont enter getFalse.
bool a = getTrue() || getFalse(); 

// Since a is false it wont enter getTrue.
bool b = getFalse() && getTrue(); 

// Since b is false it wont enter getTrue.
b = b && getTrue();
```

However the bitwise operators "|=" and "&=" aren't as smart:

```
bool a = getTrue();
a |= getFalse(); // a has no chance to get false but it still enters the function.

a = getFalse();
a &= getTrue(); // a has no chance to get true but still performs this operation.
```

I wondered why they don't work in the same logical way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One clarification:

The operators `&=` and `|=` are NOT bitwise operators when evaluated on `bool`s - they are logical operators, but they are the equivalent of `x = x & y` and `x = x | y`, which do not short circuit like `&&` and `||` do.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx):

> The & operator performs a bitwise logical AND operation on integral operands and logical AND on bool operands.

The designers *could* have implemented `||=` and `&&=`, but since they would *only* be appropriate for boolean types, there's not much value there.

Comment: What happens in an operation like `2 & true` in C#? That is when the `&` you are evaluating has both int and a bool operands. `&` is defined for two int operands, or two bool operands, but not one of each, so one of the operands need to be converted to bool, or to int so that they match, correct? So, my question is this: will `2 & true` turn into a `int & int` aka `2 & 1` aka `0` (false if converted to bool) or a `bool & bool` aka `true & true` aka `true` in C#?

Comment: @Apriori `2 & true` will not compile.  You cannot convert `bool` to `int` or vice-versa in C#.

Answer (score 8):

[D Stanley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23634889/1043380) is correct; your error is in thinking of `&` as being "bitwise" when applied to `bool`. It is better to think of `&` and `&&` as being the eager and lazy versions of logical AND when applied to `bool`.

Now here's a question that you didn't ask, but is actually the more interesting question:

> Why is there a non-short-circuiting version of AND and OR for `bool` in the first place?  That is, why would you ever say `exprX & exprY` instead of `exprX && exprY`?

The bad reason is: expression `exprY` might have a side effect that you want to always happen regardless of the value of `exprX`.  This is a bad reason because it's a questionable practice to use an expression both for its side effects and its value.

The good reason is: it can be faster to compute `&` than `&&`.

How is that possible? Surely if we can avoid computing the right hand side some of the time then we can *always* save time on average, right?

Wrong wrong wrong.  `z = x && y`  will be generated as code that has the structure:

```
if x goto CONSEQUENCE
z = false
goto DONE
CONSEQUENCE: z = y
DONE:
```

That's a lot of instructions compared to simply computing `x & y` and assigning the result to `z`, and large code takes more time to load off disk, more time to jit compile, and uses up more space in the processor cache.

Moreover, those instructions contain a conditional branch and a non-conditional branch, increasing dramatically the number of *basic blocks* which the jitter must handle. (A "basic block" is a section of code with a clear start and finish such that if there are no exceptions, all the code in the basic block executes.) The jitter might choose to eschew certain optimizations when the number of basic blocks it has to analyze gets too large.

Worst of all, any conditional branch gives the CPU an opportunity for its branch predictor to make the wrong choice, which can have serious performance repercussions in some cases.

Now, this is not to say that you should never use `&&` for bools; there's no program yet whose dramatic success in the marketplace is attributable to the use of this nano-optimization. I point it out merely because it is not entirely obvious why there should be a non-short-circuiting logical operator on bools at all.

Comment: Very interesting, that is something I've wondered in the past! Though now I'm curious why that feature made it onto the "implemented" list, rather than languishing under "nice to have".

Comment: @BenAaronson: Well, first of all it is a *very* easy feature; if you already have any binary operators, adding one more isn't hard. Second, it would be strange to be in a world where arbitrary classes could have user-defined `&` operators but `bool` did not have one, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for the affirmation - now if you can confirm my conjecture that the value of implementing `&&=` and `||=` is not worth the cost I can retire a happy man. :)

Comment: @DStanley: Oddly enough when I wrote my April Fools Day post about crazy compound operators I did not even think to include `&&=` or `||=`. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/01/compound-assignment-part-two.aspx  That's how far from my mind they were. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is whether you're using [`|`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx)/[`&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) or [`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)/[`&&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx). The latter short-circuit (what you call "smart"), while the former do not (this is the only difference between the operators when dealing with boolean types). Since there are no `&&=` or `||=` operators, you're only noticing the `&=` and `|=`, which, as the symbols suggest, do not short-circuit.

I think it's likely that `&=` and `|=` exist but `&&=` and `||=` do not because of the formers' use in numeric types, where short-circuiting doesn't make sense.