# Is it ok to use bitwise operator in place of a logical operator like OR

Tags: c#, logical-operators

This may be stupid.but i have a simple doubt
Suppose i have the following check in a function

```
bool Validate(string a , string b)
{
    if(a == null || b == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Is it ok to use bitwise OR for validation as shown below

```
if(a == null | b == null)
```

Comment: Did you try it? I'm not sure if this makes any difference when compiled

Comment: Yeah it works.But not sure if its right

Comment: When used with `bool` values, `|` is **not** a bitwise operator - cf. [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx): "For bool operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands"

Comment: `|` and `&` don't short circuit.

Comment: @ShaijuJanardhanan - I've asked a similar question and got some good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634610/why-arent-bitwise-operators-as-smart-as-logical-and-or-operators

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In boolean expressions (rather than integers etc), the main difference is: short-circuiting. `||` short-circuits. `|` does not. In most cases you **want** short-circuiting, so `||` is much much more common. In your case, it won't matter, so `||` should probably be used as the more expected choice.

The times it matters is:

```
if(politics.IsCeasefire() | army.LaunchTheRockets()) {
    // ...
}
```

vs:

```
if(politics.IsCeasefire() || army.LaunchTheRockets()) {
    // ...
}
```

The first **always does both** (assuming there isn't an exception thrown); the second doesn't launch the rockets if a ceasefire was called.

Comment: Rockets are the best side-effect example ever :)

Comment: Personally, in this case I would prefer `if(!politics.IsCeasefire()){army.LaunchTheRockets();}`.  Excluding things like memoization, I don't like hiding side effects my conditionals.

Comment: @Brian don't bring logic to a rocket launching fight!

Answer (score 1):

In this case (with `bool` arguments) the `|` operator is not a bitwise operator. It's just a non-short-circuiting version of the logical `or`(`||`).

The same goes for `&` vs. `&&` - it's just a non-short-circuiting version of logical `and`.

The difference can be seen with side-effects, for example in

```
bool Check()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Evaluated!");
    return true;
}

// Short-circuits, only evaluates the left argument.
if (Check() || Check()) { ... }

// vs.

// No short circuit, evaluates both.
if (Check() | Check()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, because when used on things that evaluate to `bool`, the "bitwise" operators carry out logical operations just the same. You might find it less efficient, though. The logical operators in C# will short-circuit, meaning they'll skip evaluation of the second expression if the answer can be deduced from the first. So in your example, if `a == null` turns out to be true, then `||` would return `true` immediately, while `|` would go ahead and check `b == null` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented upon, the code is indeed 'ok'.

Using the single pipe '|' will evaluate all expressions before returning the result.
'||' can be more efficient, since it ceases as soon as an expression evaluates to true.